# Sorting an HTML select with Javascript. Parameter not working

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-select

I have 2 select's.  I want to move items between them.  They should be sorted.  I grabbed some code from SO, and am experiencing something weird.  When I pass the element as a parameter to the sort function, it doesn't work.  When I explicitly get the element in the sort function it works perfectly.  Look at the first line in the sort function and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Here's my PHP part.

```
   echo "
    <div><select id='listBox1' class='form-control select-manage-category' size='5'>
        <option value=1>1-text</option>
        <option value=2>2-text</option>
        <option value=3>3-text</option>
        <option value=4>4-text</option>
    </select></div>

    <input id='add-category' onclick='ClickAdd()'  name='add' type='button' value='Add Item'>
    <input id='remove-category' onclick='ClickRemove()' name='add' type='button' value='Remove Item'>

    <div>
        <select id='listBox2' class='form-group percent-100' size='5'></select>
    </div>
    ";
    
    echo "<script>";
    include 'bstest.js';
    echo "</script>";
```

And, this is my JS (bstest.js).

```
function ClickAdd() 
{
    // get the 'left' listbox.
    var e = document.getElementById('listBox1');

    // get the text and value of selected item.
    var eText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var eVal = e.value;
        
    // create the new element
    var opt = document.createElement('option');     
    opt.text = eText;
    opt.value = eVal;       
        
    // add it to the 'right' listbox.
    document.getElementById('listBox2').options.add(opt);
        
    // now remove it from the 'left' list.
    value = e.selectedIndex;
    e.removeChild(e[value]);
    
    sortSelect(e);
    
}

function ClickRemove()
{
    // get the 'right' listbox.
    var e = document.getElementById('listBox2');
    
    // get the text and value of selected item.
    var eText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var eVal = e.value;

    // create the new element
    var opt = document.createElement('option');     
    opt.text = eText;
    opt.value = eVal;       

    // add it to the 'left' listbox.
    document.getElementById('listBox1').options.add(opt);

    // now remove it from the 'right' list.
    value = e.selectedIndex;
    e.removeChild(e[value]);
    
    sortSelect(e);
}

function sortSelect(selectToSort) 
{
    
    //selectToSort = document.getElementById('listBox1');       // works.  If I comment it, it doesn't work.

    var arrOptions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < selectToSort.options.length; i++)  
    {
        arrOptions[i] = [];
        arrOptions[i][0] = selectToSort.options[i].value;
        arrOptions[i][1] = selectToSort.options[i].text;
        arrOptions[i][2] = selectToSort.options[i].selected;
    }
    arrOptions.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < selectToSort.options.length; i++)  
    {
        selectToSort.options[i].value = arrOptions[i][0];
        selectToSort.options[i].text = arrOptions[i][1];
        selectToSort.options[i].selected = arrOptions[i][2];
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I suggest creating two arrays of objects like `[{ value: '', text: '', selected: false }]`. Move items back and forth between the arrays and sort the arrays. Once you have the arrays where you want them, empty the `select`s and create `option`s based on the arrays. Then you won't have to worry about passing references to elements and all that.

Comment: What @HereticMonkey said. You should be separating model and presentation here. You don't want to be moving elements around the DOM tree unnecessarily. Generate the select items from two arrays and move items between the arrays.

Comment: I understand and agree.  This is test code to prove an idea.  Still, out of curiosity, why doesn't it work?